# How to read same inputstream twice without both inputstreams stopping from working

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, datainputstream

I am trying to create a small application that can send logs with text over a socket. As the socket is accepted the inputstream of that socket will be stored in a HashMap like this.

```
private HashMap<Integer,InputStream> allinputsstreams = new 
HashMap<Integer,InputStream>();
```

after that I will create a new JFrame for that current inputstream

```
public LogListener(int socketid, SocketListener socketlistener, Gui gui) {
    this.socketid = socketid;
    this.gui = gui;
    this.inputstream = socketlistener.getClient(socketid);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Log listener");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(framewidth,frameheight));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    logarea = new JTextArea();
    frame.add(logarea);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addWindowListener(this);
    listenthread = new Thread(this);
    listenthread.start();
}
```

Then I use the inputstream from the list to receive the data and write it on the JFrame

```
public void run() {
    input = new DataInputStream(inputstream);
    while(!formclosed) {
        try {
            String addtext = input.readUTF();
            addtext = formatText(addtext);
            logarea.setText(logarea.getText() + addtext);
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            System.out.println("Looks like the client has been closed.");
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

This works for receiving the data on 1 JFrame, but once I open 2 JFrames(meaning opening the same inputstream twice) then none of the inputstreams work anymore. I was expecting atleast 1 inputstream would still work.

Comment: What do you mean by "none of the inputstreams work"? Do you get exceptions? Deadlock? Something else?

Comment: I don't get any exception but when I have 1 open it sends the data and writes it onto the JFrame(this is what I want) but when I open another one (opening the inputstream twice) then none of the inputstreams send the data that I need

Comment: Aren't the input streams tied to separate sockets? Why would you be reading the same input stream twice?

Comment: Yes they are but the inputstreams are put in a HashMap with a number as the key and inputstream as the value. When I open for example number 1 from that HashMap then it uses that stream. After that I open number 2 then they both work as they are different inputstreams. But when I open number 1 and after that number 1 again they both stop working.

Comment: You can't. An input stream is a stream, and the meaning of stream is that it flows past you, once. If you want to re-read it you have to recreate it, re-open the file, re-connect to the source (if you dcan), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to display the data from an input stream in two distinct views. You can't really read a plain `InputStream` twice; instead, you need some kind of buffering. So rather than trying to read it twice, I suggest modifying your code in one of two ways, both of which involve using only a single read loop for each stream:

1. Modify your read loop to update an internal buffer instead of calling `logarea.setText(logarea.getText() + addtext);`. Whenever the read loop updates the buffer, any interested views should be notified (via some sort of observer pattern that you implement) that the contents have changed.
2. Modify the read loop to update all interested views instead of having a separate read loop for each `JFrame`. The read loop would need access to a list of log areas instead of a single `logarea`. It would loop through the list and update each log area using the same logic you are now using for `logarea`.

The key thing is to never have two read loops accessing the same input stream.

Comment: I think I kind of get it now and I will change my code thank you for your answer.

Comment: Great! It worked for me. I'm writing stream data into object of ByteArrayOutputStream and closing the input stream and socket immediately. Then when ever I need the data, I could use it from ByteArrayOutputStream's Object.
Correct me, If I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada - Sounds like the right approach to me.